# Como puedo reinicar el estilo de mi radio button creado de forma manual?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, radiobutton

Cree un conjunto de nuevos radiobuttons, y si se observa bien están como activos los tres y cambian a color amarillo, pero quiero que cuando le de click nuevamente al radio button ese color cambie a blanco y el left de la bola amarilla regrese a 0, pero eso no lo hace solo se ejecuta cuando le doy el primer clic pero no el segundo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo de CSS:

```
input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"]{
  display: none;
}

.container label {
  position: relative;
}

.container span::before,
.container span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.container span.radio:hover {
  cursor: pointer;

}


.container span.radio::before {
  left: -52px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #A8AAC1;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.container span.radio::after {
  left: -49px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #6C788A;
  transition: left .25s, background-color .25s;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span.radio::after {
  left: -27px;
  background-color: #EBFF43;
}
```

Codigo HTML

```
          <div class="container" id="conEducativo" onclick="ClickRdio(0,'conEducativo');">
              <input type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-1">
              <label for="radio-1"><span class="radio">Educativo</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="container" id="contBancario" onclick="ClickRdio(1,'contBancario');">
              <input type="radio" name="group2" id="radio-2">
              <label for="radio-2"><span class="radio">Bancario</span></label>
          </div>

                            <div class="container" id="contAduana" onclick="ClickRdio(2,'contAduana');">
              <input type="radio" name="group3" id="radio-3">
              <label for="radio-3"><span class="radio">Aduanero</span></label>
          </div>
```

Forma que lo intente hacer 1:

```
input[type="radio"]:not(checked) + label span.radio::after {
  left: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Forma que lo intente hacer 2:

```
function ClickRdio(id, idElement) {
        switch(id) {
            case 0:
                $("#" + idElement + "").addClass("activeRadio");
                $("#contBancario").removeClass("activeRadio");
                $("#contAduana").removeClass("activeRadio");
                $("label span.radio").addClass("initRadio");
                break;
            case 1:
                $("#" + idElement + "").addClass("activeRadio");
                $("#conEducativo").removeClass("activeRadio");
                $("#contAduana").removeClass("activeRadio");
                $("label span.radio").addClass("initRadio");
                break;
            case 2:
                $("#" + idElement + "").addClass("activeRadio");
                $("#contBancario").removeClass("activeRadio");
                $("#conEducativo").removeClass("activeRadio");
                $("label span.radio").addClass("initRadio");
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Buen día, por favor explícate mejor para que puedan ayudarte, en el primer párrafo podrías mirar que no se entiende muy bien que quieres.

Comment: @StivenGómez ya lo mejor, espero que asi se comprenda mejor, saludos.